# Pesquisando existência de registro antes de incluir um novo (Yii 2)

Tags: yii2

**Olá Pessoal!**

No **create.php** de uma view (ANOLETIVO), faço a pesquisa se existe registro na tabela com status = 1. Se existir não deve ser permitida a nova inclusão.

Já fiz isso no **Yii 1** mas estou "apanhando" no **Yii 2**.

Vejam como implementei o script do create.php:

```html
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\ANOLETIVO */
?>

<?php
$this->title = 'Iniciar Ano do Assessoramento';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Anoletivos', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<div class="anoletivo-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php
    /*
     * As linhas a seguir foram implementadas para NÃO PERMITIR iniciar ano novo, sem encerrar antes ano já iniciado.
     */
    $registros=$this->findAll(['condition'=>'ANO_LETIVO_STATUS = 1']);
     if (count($registros)>0){
    ?>
         <b>Atenção!</b> Existe Ano de Assessoramento não encerrado!<br><br>
         <?php 
          $link = CController::createUrl('anoletivo/index');  
          echo CHtml::linkButton(CHtml::Button('Voltar',['class'=>'btn btn-alert']),['href'=>$link]); 
         ?>
    <?php 
     }else{
      echo $this->renderPartial('_form', ['model'=>$model]);
     }
    ?>

</div>
```

A seguir vejam a mensagem de erro quando tento acessar a funcionalidade de inclusão de um novo ano letivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço toda e qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim

```html
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use app\models\ANOLETIVO;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\ANOLETIVO */
?>

<?php
$this->title = 'Iniciar Ano do Assessoramento';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Anoletivos', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<div class="anoletivo-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php
    /*
     * As linhas a seguir foram implementadas para NÃO PERMITIR iniciar ano novo, sem encerrar antes ano já iniciado.
     */
    $registros= ANOLETIVO::findAll(['condition'=>'ANO_LETIVO_STATUS = 1']);
     if (count($registros)>0){
    ?>
         <b>Atenção!</b> Existe Ano de Assessoramento não encerrado!<br><br>
         <?php 
          $link = Url::toRoute('anoletivo/index');  
          echo Html::a('Voltar',['class'=>'btn btn-alert']),['href'=>$link]); 
         ?>
    <?php 
     }else{
      echo $this->renderPartial('_form', ['model'=>$model]);
     }
    ?>

</div>
```